# Relay activation and power step down

Tags: relay, surface-mount, switching, analog-switch

I have one single pin and I would need to activate a relay.
After half a second I need to step down the voltage of the relay from 12V to 3.3V.
I've been able to accomplish this task using an LTV6994 in conjunction with couple of NPN and a relay. basically when cpu pin send signal (RELAY) it activate a relay at 12V by an npn ( not in pic) and the ltc6994 at the same time. LTC6994 create delay in signal from cpu (RELAY) and activate a second  relay  ( in pic) switching down to 3.3V.
This works but i suppose there's a magic alternative I have not considered. Do you have any suggestion ( better if full smd made)? I attach the schema I'm using now
[image]

Comment: You’ve told us how you’re doing it but not what you want to achieve and why. Assuming the source signal is from a microcontroller, I’d use pwm to control the effective voltage to the relay. Then you’d only need one mosfet and a resistor. To turn the relay on, you’d have the microcontroller output a duty cycle of 100% then decrease this to achieve your holding voltage. This ends up being an efficient means of lowering the power to the relay.

Comment: hello, I simply need to open and close a relay 12V and lowering his voltage to 3.3V but I only have a single pin available  to do that . this is the goal